# Can you solve this puzzle of mine?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Hundreds of boxes in columns and rows

In a room with two thousand windows

I start opening the boxes, I go on my way

Some of them change color, the rest of them are gray

The tension increases, it is part of the fun

I'm looking for glasses to wear in the sun

Blue, Green, Green, Red

Just as expected

Black Purple Red Green

The fastest I have ever been

Green Green Green Blue

Nothing wrong, this must be true

Green, Blue, Red, Black

Something's wrong, I'm way off track!

Tell me now, why is this wrong?

Tell me quickly, I don't have long!

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 19):

Are you talking about

> Minesweeper?

Hundreds of boxes in columns and rows

> The minesweeper grid

In a room with two thousand windows

> Windows 2000

I'm looking for glasses to wear in the sun

> The icon that comes up on solving the puzzle

Blue, Green, Green, Red etc.

> Different possible combinations

Comment: Looks like the question's title contains a clue.

Comment: You have basically seen most of it, but you are strictly speaking not answering the puzzle. Also two thousand windows does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the first answer posted that the puzzle described...

> Minesweeper

but that was not the solution to what the riddle was asking.

> Note that each colour of the number in a tile corresponds to the number of bombs around the tile.
>
>   TLDR: The colours in the riddle correspond to the values that appear after making a move in Minesweeper. What I did was prove that at least one combination of moves described in the puzzle is not possible by contradiction. I mapped out some of my moves in Excel to show why it doesn't work. The last move involves mapping a square with 7 bombs around it but that is shown to be impossible. 
>
>
>   Below is one of the solutions I've found for the riddle. It is possible to prove that this arrangement is not possible in any combination of moves but I haven't finished writing the program for that yet. I've omitted most steps but the logic is to follow the corresponding colours/numbers to place down the correct number of bombs.

Legend:

> g = gray area, no bombs and no numbers assigned (yet)
>   M = indicates tile click with the move number beside the M; M2 is the 2nd move
>   b = bomb
>   1, 2, 3, 4 = same as in Minesweeper rules, indicates number of bombs adjacent to the tile
>
>   You'll notice that by the last move in the 4th image, there is no way to ensure that the tile labelled 7 is surrounded by 7 bombs without contradicting other numbered tiles.
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9q3g.jpg
>   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDZGW.jpg
>   [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qysUG.jpg
>   [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL9yC.jpg